# Lost reference of Fragments in FragmentPagerAdapter

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, fragmentpageradapter

I have a simple FragmentPagerAdapter :

```
public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
    pagerAdapterList = new ArrayList<>();
    super(fm);
}

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    PagerAdapter fragment;
    if (position > pagerAdapterList.size() - 1) {
                fragment = new PagerAdapter(followRequests.get(position));
                pagerAdapterList.add(fragment);

            } else
                return pagerAdapterList.get(position);

    return fragment;
}

        public int removeView (ViewPager pager, int position)
    {
        pager.setAdapter (null);
        pagerAdapterList.remove (position);
        data.remove (position);
        pager.setAdapter (this);

        return position;
    }

        @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
        getItem(position);
        return super.instantiateItem(container, position);
    }

@Override
public int getCount() {
return data.size();
}

}
```

and PagerAdapter class:

```
public class PagerAdapter extends Fragment {

Data data;
private View overlayView;

public PagerAdapter() {
}

public PagerAdapter(Data data) {
    this.data= data;
}

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.notification_header_fragment_pager, container, false);
    TextView id_txtView = (TextView) 
    overlayView = (View) rootView.findViewById(R.id.viewOverlay);

    //bind some data for example id_txtView.setText(data.getText());

    return rootView;
}

public void showOverlayView() {
    if(overlayView != null)
    overlayView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}
}
```

first I call

> removeView(mViewPager, position);

then I get new data, and then call

> adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

All things work fine and I can bind new data in PagerAdapter and show it on View Pager.

But when I call

> ((PagerAdapter) adapter.getItem(mViewPager.getCurrentItem())).showOverlayView();

I get current fragment without any reference to its ui components(like overlayView) and they are null !!

what's my wrong?
Please help me, Thanks.

Comment: Did you try to debug your app?

Comment: @Krish yes, I debug it and find out that refrences will get lost, but really can't understand what's my wrong